# \usepackage{subfig} giving captionlablelfont errors

Tags: captions, subfloats, subfig

While using \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} I get an error like in the image below
[image]

And the chapter 6 where figure is included has the following code.

```
\begin{figure}[h!] 
        \centering
        \subfloat[a)]{\includegraphics[width=.35\linewidth, scale=0.5]{registered1.png}}\hspace{4mm}
        \subfloat[b)]{\includegraphics[width=.35\linewidth, scale=0.5]{registered2.png}}
        \caption{FCC of MS bands registered to a) SAR Image de-noised by enhanced Lee filter b)SAR Image de-noised by wavelet filtering}
        \label{Registration}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% This is part of "main" file
\documentclass[12pt,openright,twoside]{thesis}  %12pt is larger than 11pt
\usepackage{titlesec}
   \titleformat{\chapter}
      {\normalfont\large}{Chapter \thechapter:}{1em}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabls}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{subeqn}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage[inner=3.3cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\graphicspath{F:/SY_MTech/Manali/Paper}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}


\newcommand{\tbsp}{\rule{0pt}{12pt}} %used to get a vertical distance after \hline
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}     
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.9in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.50in}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}    %use this setting if the printer makes the the top margin 1/2 inch instead of 1 inch
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.3cm}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{.1cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{.4in}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\sizetwelvefixed}{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]% NEW
    {\fontfamily{ptm}\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}{\huge}% NEW
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}% NEW


\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%55

\include{Titlepage} %(must be first, required, non-numbered)
\cleardoublepage
\include{certificate}
\cleardoublepage
\include{Approval}
\cleardoublepage
\include{Abstract} %(must follow Abstract, required, non-numbered)


%Pages from this point start at lower-case Roman number ii)
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}

%\include{Preface}  %(if present, start at lower-case Roman number ii)
%\include{Foreword} %(if present, lower-case Roman)
%\include{Dedication} %(if present, lower-case Roman)
\include{Acknowledgments} %(if present, lower-case Roman)

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\small\normalsize
\tableofcontents %(required, lower-case Roman)
\newpage
%\listoftables %(if present, lower-case Roman)
%\newpage
\listoffigures %(if present, lower-case Roman)
\newpage
% LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\include{Abbreviations}

\newpage
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\small\normalsize

%Pages from this point start at Arabic numeral 1
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\include{Chapter3}
\include{Chapter4}
\include{Chapter5}
\include{chapter6}
\include{chapter7}
%\include{supertabular}
\titleformat{\chapter}
      {\normalfont\large}{Appendix \thechapter:}{1em}{}
%\include{AppendixA}
%\include{AppendixB}
%\include{AppendixC}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\small\normalsize
%\include{Bibliography}
%When using Bibtex, delete the previous line and use the following
%three lines.  

%\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
%\bibliography{Galactic,Dottie} %replace "Galactic,Dottie" with the
%                 file name(s) of your bib file(s)

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{Citations}
\end{document}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se!. in my documents your code snipped work fine! to see, what is going wrong in your document, you had to provide complete but small document beginning with `\documentclasss{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, which gives reported error.

Comment: Hi, I have posted complete document beginning with \documentclasss{...} and ending with \end{document}.Please have a look and suggest anything if you may.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a document class called `thesis`. In the old days the `caption` package assumed that the `thesis` document class available on CTAN [1] is used, but there are many private document classes called `thesis` as well. You are using such class, and therefore the `caption` package tries to use commands from the CTAN `thesis` class like `\cph@font` which fails.

I fixed this on 2009/11/15.

What could you do? Either

1) Update your TeX installation. I'm sorry, but I cannot support versions of the `caption` package which are more than 8 years old. If updating TeX is not an option for you, try:

2) Add `\captionsetup{format=plain,labelfont={},textfont={}}` right after `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`. I haven't tested it, but it might work. If not, try:

3) Rename your `thesis` class, e.g. by renaming `thesis.cls` to `mythesis.cls` and changing `\documentclass{thesis}` to `\documentclass{mythesis}`.

[1] https://ctan.org/pkg/thesis

Comment: Thanks. \captionsetup{labelfont={},textfont={}} right after \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} worked.Thank You again

Comment: @ManaliKedar BTW: You are using Windows 10 but an TeX installation from 2009? Or do you have a local copy of `caption.sty` and `caption3.sty` from 2009 in your document folder? If yes, deleting these files will fix your problem, too.